# How to generate private key in live environment

Tags: private-key, yodlee

In yodlee deveopment environment, I can't see the private key I need to signed the generated jwt, i see the private key in sandbox, but can't see it in development

Someway I have a private key that isn't working (can't remember how i have this private key, as this is a development that i started time ago, and it stop and now i'm getting it again)

Answer (score 0):

In the yodlee sandbox, you are issued your RSA keypair.  This is to speed things along for you.

Once you get out of the sandbox environment, you need to generate your own RSA key pair, and upload your public key with Yodlee while keeping your private key secure, confidential, secret, and not in any mobile devices.

Google "How do I generate an RSA keypair" for info on the command line tools and other sources.